# Notify a specified tread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I didn't find anything on the Internet about this, so I'm asking here.

Is there a command in C++ to notify a specified thread and not a casual one?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about the problem and what you're aiming for. So please, update your question.

Comment: `std::condition_variable::notify_one()`

Answer (score 4):

Use one `std::condition_variable` for each event you want to wait for.

Comment: I tried, but it just notify a casual thread.

Comment: If you want to notify a specific thread, use a separate `std::condition_variable` for it.  Do not use that `std::condition_variable` for other threads.